# Python concurrent.futures calling same function twice

Tags: python, concurrent-programming

I have no problem using concurrent.futures if all my processes are started from different functions.  But if I want to call the same function with different parameters I can't seem to get the syntax right.  This is what I got so far but it doesn't work:

```
tasks = ((serial_port_local, serial_options_local, serial_port_remote, serial_options_remote, "local"),
(serial_port_remote, serial_options_remote, serial_port_local, serial_options_local, "remote"))

for task in zip(tasks, executor.map(serial_cross_over, tasks)):
    print (task)
```

This is the error but I don't grok it:

```
TypeError: serial_cross_over() missing 4 required positional arguments: 'receive_serial_options', 'send_serial_port', 'send_serial_options', and 'source'
```

Actually I don't really grok why its complicated at all.  Shouldn't I just be able to do:

```
executor.submit(some_function(parameter1))
executor.submit(some_function(parameter2))
```

But that doesn't work.  The program hangs on the second submit.  Why?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that serial_cross_over takes 4 arguments (correct me if I'm wrong) and you do not provide them when .map so,
maybe take a look at this answer: [Pass multiple parameters to concurrent.futures.Executor.map?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6785226/pass-multiple-parameters-to-concurrent-futures-executor-map)

```
tasks = ((serial_port_local, serial_options_local, serial_port_remote, serial_options_remote, "local"), (serial_port_remote, serial_options_remote, serial_port_local, serial_options_local, "remote"))

for task in zip(executor.map(lambda p: f(*p), tasks)):
    pass
```

As for why doesn't executor.submit work as expected, I cannot tell without further details. Have you tried like this?:

```
with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=1) as executor:
    future = executor.submit(some_function, parameter1)
    print(future.result())
```