# How do I replace a nested loop with concurrent.futures?

Tags: python, concurrent.futures

Say, I have the following loops:

```py
for i in range(50):
   for j in range(50):
      for k in range(50):
         for l in range(50):
             some_function(i,j,k,l)
```

`some_function` happens to be a web scraper for a lot of small files, so it makes sense to parallelize this.

But as far as I can tell, concurrent.futures only accepts one iterator, so I'm not sure how to approach this. What I *could* do is express (two of) them as a single iterator like:

```py
def in_between_function(a):
    x = math.floor(a/5)
    y = a % y
    some_function(x,y)

with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=100) as executor:
   future = executor.map(in_between_function, range(50*50))
```

That doesn't look too bad but I want to do it properly; if I extend this to more iterators, negative numbers or if the iterator is not linear then this will be a nightmare to maintain.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pass multiple parameters to concurrent.futures.Executor.map?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6785226/pass-multiple-parameters-to-concurrent-futures-executor-map)

Comment: and to generate the multi-variable range, use [`itertools.product`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6785226/pass-multiple-parameters-to-concurrent-futures-executor-map) with `repeat=4`

Comment: I would like to avoid generating a list of (potentially) millions of tuples if possible. Should I?

Comment: `product` returns a generator, it doesn't create a massive list :)