# Passing a function that takes **kwargs into concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor.map

Tags: python, keyword-argument, concurrent.futures

I've just begun learning concurrent programming in Python.

I created a function which takes one positional argument and then **kwargs.

Code:

```
def download_from_api(api_client_method, **kwargs):
    try:
        response = api_client_method(**kwargs)
        return response
    except api.exceptions.APIException as e:
        print(f'{kwargs}: {api_client_method.__name__} - {e})
```

I'd like to pass this function to `concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor().map()` object.

Below is the code i used for trying, passing everything as positional `args`, but it didnt work:

```
these_should_be_passed_as_keyword_args = ['A', 'B']
n = len(these_should_be_passed_as_keyword_args)
functions = [api_client.relevant_method] * n

with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
    results = executor.map(download_from_api, functions, these_should_be_passed_as_keyword_args)
```

Any help is really appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some good examples here:
[Pass multiple parameters to concurrent.futures.Executor.map?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6785226/pass-multiple-parameters-to-concurrent-futures-executor-map)

Alternatively, I prefer using `.submit()`
Here are the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html), and here is a [tutorial](https://superfastpython.com/threadpoolexecutor-in-python/)

As I cant execute your download_from_api function, here is a basic example with a function that just prints random generated kwargs:

```
import string
import random
import concurrent.futures as cf


def your_function(argument, **kwargs):
    print(argument, kwargs)


random_kwargs = [{
    ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase) for _ in range(4)):
        ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase) for _ in range(4))
} for _ in range(10)]

with cf.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
    futures = [executor.submit(your_function, argument, **kwargs) 
               for argument, kwargs in enumerate(random_kwargs)]
```

Comment: Thank you! I'll have to study the difference between `map()` and `submit()` more. I started with `map()` as I read it's usually better when converting `for` loops.

Comment: Especially when working with an API you probably want to send a lot of requests and then work with them as soon as you get the data. Another useful function in that context is `for future in cf.as_completed(futures)`that lets you loop over the submitted futures and collect their data whenever they are completed.