# How to make `concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor().map` work with kwonly args?

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing, concurrent.futures

How to make `concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor().map` work with  kwonly args? Is this even possible?

With positional args:

```py
def worker_function(x):
    # Return the square of the passed argument:
    return x ** 2

# concurrent.futures example:
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor
with ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
    squares = list(executor.map(worker_function, (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)))
```

How to make this work for a function accepting  keyword only args:

```
def worker_function(*, x):
    # Return the square of the passed argument:
    return x ** 2
```

I tried this

```
with ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
    squares = list(executor.map(worker_function, (dict(x=x) for x in (1, 2))))
```

which fails because dict is not passed as kwargs for some reason

```
TypeError: worker_function() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

okay, something like this seems to work:

```
with ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
    # Using lambda, unpacks the dict (**f) into hello(**kwargs)
    kwargs_names = (dict(x=x, y=2) for x in range(4))
    executor.map(lambda f: worker_function(**f), kwargs_names)

print(squares)
```

[ref](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67341324)