# How to pass a constant value (a list) to concurrent.futures.Executor.map?

Tags: python, concurrent.futures

Related question that doesn't answer my exact use-case:

[Pass multiple parameters to concurrent.futures.Executor.map?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6785226/pass-multiple-parameters-to-concurrent-futures-executor-map)

I have a function that takes 2 arguments. The second argument is a list and in my case constant for all calls to `executor.map`.

```
a = [1,2,3] # values to map and pass as single value
b = ["constant", "values"]
for result in executor.map(f, a, b): # how to pass always all values of b to f?
    # do stuff
```

I don't rely on concurrent, I could also use multiprocessing if that makes this possible or easier.

Comment: why not make a partial function `lambda a: f(a, b)`?

Comment: Maybe use `from functools import partial;` and then `executor.map(partial(f, b=b), a)`. There `partial(f, b=b)` creates another function, where the `b` argument is filled in

Comment: lambda doesn't work due to pickling error, seems to be a known limitation of multiprocessing.

Comment: using `partial` leads to `BrokenProcessPool: A process in the process pool was terminated abruptly while the future was running or pending.`

Comment: You should not be using the Executor class directly. Use either ThreadPoolExecutor or ProcessPoolExecutor according to your precise needs. See: https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html

Comment: @Codist yeah thats clear. I fell into an age old trap, not the first time, that prototyping in jupyter and there you simply get the BrokenProcessPool error when using a function defined in jupyter cell.

Comment: Given the almost constant flow of issues that people have with Jupyter, I'm amazed that anyone actually uses it. Controversial? Probably

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of how you could use *partial* from *functools* to achieve this:

```
from functools import partial
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor, ThreadPoolExecutor

USE_THREADS = False

def process(a, b):
    print(a)
    print(b)

def main():
    v = [1, 2, 3]
    c = ["constant", "values"]
    with (ThreadPoolExecutor if USE_THREADS else ProcessPoolExecutor)() as executor:
        executor.map(partial(process, c), v)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Set USE_THREADS to True if you want to use multithreading or False for multiprocessing

**Output:**

```
['constant', 'values']
1
['constant', 'values']
2
['constant', 'values']
3
```

Answer (score 0):

I went with the solution from the other thread that initinally didn't work for me for the jupyter reasons mentioned in the comments.

```
from itertools import repeat
for result in executor.map(f, repeat(a), c):
    pass
```

If `a` is a list, `repeat` will send the entire list for each function call. Advantage is you don't need to adjust order of function arguments like with `partial`